# Evaluating constants/scalars inside `dplyr`'s `across()`

Tags: r, dplyr, across

From my point of view, this seems like a fairly easy thing to do, but I'm having such trouble trying to get this to work.

What I'm trying to do, via `mutate()` and `across()`, is simply to make some variables just evaluate to a constant or a scalar within a custom function.

I'll demonstrate this with a non-`across()` implementation:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

vars <- c("mpg", "cyl")

Test_Function <- function(.data, .vars) {
    
    Data_Frame <- .data %>% 
        
        mutate(
            !!.vars[1] := "Something", 
            !!.vars[2] := 2L
        ) %>% 
        
        select({{.vars}}) %>% 
        
        as_tibble()
    
    return(Data_Frame)
}

mtcars %>% Test_Function(vars)
#> # A tibble: 32 x 2
#>    mpg         cyl
#>    <chr>     <int>
#>  1 Something     2
#>  2 Something     2
#>  3 Something     2
#>  4 Something     2
#>  5 Something     2
#>  6 Something     2
#>  7 Something     2
#>  8 Something     2
#>  9 Something     2
#> 10 Something     2
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

When I try to get the same thing accomplished via `across()`, I can't get it to work:

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

vars <- c("mpg", "cyl")

Test_Function <- function(.data, .vars) {
    
    Data_Frame <- 
        
        .data %>%
        
        mutate(
            across(!!.vars, "Something"), # Doesn't work
            across(!!.vars, ~ .x := "Something"), # purrr-style doesn't work
            across(!!.vars, ~ assign(.x, "Something")), # purrr-style with assign() doesn't work
            across(!!.vars, assign, "Something") # Regular assign() doesn't work
        ) %>%
        
        select({{.vars}}) %>%
        
        as_tibble()
    
    return(Data_Frame)
}

mtcars %>% Test_Function(vars)
```

As an aside, I wish I could provide `across()` some variables that don't exist in `.data` so I can easily create *new* columns without having to do it manually inside of `mutate()`, but as of the time of writing that doesn't work (yet?).

**EDIT:**

@MrFlick/@JonSpring,and @TimTeaFan gave suggestions that worked for me; the former for just one value, the latter for a list of values. I'll provide minimal reprexes for both of what I went with. Thanks everyone for the help!

@MrFlick/@JonSpring's suggestion, returning a single value:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

vars <- c("mpg", "cyl")

Test_Function <- function(.data, .vars) {
    
    Data_Frame <- 
        
        .data %>%
        
        mutate(
            across(!!.vars, ~ "Something"), # I was so close to this initially, I just missed the tilde.
        ) %>%
        
        select({{.vars}}) %>%
        
        as_tibble()
    
    return(Data_Frame)
}

mtcars %>% Test_Function(vars)
#> # A tibble: 32 x 2
#>    mpg       cyl      
#>    <chr>     <chr>    
#>  1 Something Something
#>  2 Something Something
#>  3 Something Something
#>  4 Something Something
#>  5 Something Something
#>  6 Something Something
#>  7 Something Something
#>  8 Something Something
#>  9 Something Something
#> 10 Something Something
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

And now @TimTeaFan's suggestion:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

varlist <- 
    
    list(
        "mpg" = "Something",
        "cyl" = 2L
    )

vars <- c("mpg", "cyl")

Test_Function <- function(.data, .varlist, .vars) {
    
    Data_Frame <- 
        
        .data %>%
        
        mutate(
            !!! .varlist # I haven't really undstood the big-bang operator (!!!) before now, so this was a great demonstration!
        ) %>%
        
        select(!!.vars) %>%
        
        as_tibble()
    
    return(Data_Frame)
}

mtcars %>% Test_Function(varlist, vars)
#> # A tibble: 32 x 2
#>    mpg         cyl
#>    <chr>     <int>
#>  1 Something     2
#>  2 Something     2
#>  3 Something     2
#>  4 Something     2
#>  5 Something     2
#>  6 Something     2
#>  7 Something     2
#>  8 Something     2
#>  9 Something     2
#> 10 Something     2
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: What's the desired result when you run your function with `across()`. Do you just want all the columns to be "Something"? You still need to use `:=` for new variable names. `across()` can't help you with that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what `across()` would add here. Does `mutate(across(!!.vars, ~paste("Something")))` do what you want?

Comment: @JonSpring, actually you don't even need the `paste()`, right? Just `mutate(across(!!.vars, ~"Something"))`

Comment: Yes, good point!

Comment: @MrFlick Your 2nd suggestion worked! I'll add it to my original post! Thanks! I was so damn close initally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to assign scalars to a variable, then you neither need `across` nor a function to do so. You can just define a list and use the triple bang operator inside `dplyr::mutate` or, more close to your case,  `dplyr::transmute`.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

vars <- list("mpg" = "something",
             "cyl" = 2L)

mtcars <- head(mtcars)

mtcars %>% 
  transmute(!!! vars)

#>                         mpg cyl
#> Mazda RX4         something   2
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     something   2
#> Datsun 710        something   2
#> Hornet 4 Drive    something   2
#> Hornet Sportabout something   2
#> Valiant           something   2
```

If you want to create new columns programmatically in an `across` like way, then an easy {tidyverse} trick is to use `purrr::map_dfc` inside `dplyr::mutate`. Note that in the example below you can use any other function even expressions depending on other column names:

```
library(purrr)

mtcars %>%
  transmute(map_dfc(vars, ~ .x))

#>                         mpg cyl
#> Mazda RX4         something   2
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     something   2
#> Datsun 710        something   2
#> Hornet 4 Drive    something   2
#> Hornet Sportabout something   2
#> Valiant           something   2
```

I also have a package on github, {dplyover} which has a function `over` that  uses `dplyr::across`'s syntax to loop over a vector creating new columns similar to `purrr::map_dfc`. You can create column names on the fly using the `.names` argument.

```
library(dplyover) # https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover

mtcars %>% 
  transmute(over(vars, ~ .x,
                 .names = "{x}_new"))

#>                     mpg_new cyl_new
#> Mazda RX4         something       2
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     something       2
#> Datsun 710        something       2
#> Hornet 4 Drive    something       2
#> Hornet Sportabout something       2
#> Valiant           something       2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>